# which api should be used to transfer original images from the Sony qx 10 to my pc using the wifi link

Tags: sony

How can I transfer images from the camera to the computer using API?

I am trying to get the images from the camera to my pc, but I don't want to take out the sd card. Maybe the SDK can help me.

Comment: Show what you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use the device-specific API if it exists. Check out the official website- there might be the SDK with all the documents and examples. You can also contact their tech support. I bet they will give you the solution.

Comment: sony guys preffer answering on stackflow, I have downloaded SDK it was not very helpful. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 0):

You can for sure use the SDK to transfer images from your camera to your computer. You won't be able to delete the images on your camera, but you can for sure copy them. You can use the "getContentList" endPoint to list out all of the media that is on your camera. Each content item will have a url that you will then use to download the image. How you download the image will be determined by which language you use. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: can i download the images in full resolution? The images that i downloaded using the url were of diminished resolution.

Comment: You should be able to use the "setPostviewImageSize" option. Here are the options: "Original" - Original size ,  "2M"-   2M-pixel size (the actual size depends on camera models.)

Comment: will 'api.setPostviewImageSize('Original')' do the job??

Comment: when i shift the image from camera to my phone using the app, the image size is around 5MB, but when i do it with the method above the image size is about 1.5MB. I need to get the original 5 MB image.

Comment: hmm.. that is interesting. Try making a call to "getAvailablePostviewImageSize" just so we can see what options are available

Comment: Actually "eskimwier" made a good point in his answer. Are you seeing the largeUrl as listed in his answer as returned from getContentList?

Comment: the api getContentList() is not supported on camera qx10

Comment: You may need the latest firmware update. Try updating the firmware and see if that helps : https://esupport.sony.com/US/p/swu-download.pl?mdl=DSCQX10&upd_id=9741&os_group_id=26

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get the image from the URL provided in the response to `actTakePicture` or from a URL in `getContentList`?

Here's an example entry returned from my camera for `getContentList`:

```
{
    "content": {
        "original": [
            {
                "fileName": "DSC00487.JPG",
                "stillObject": "jpeg",
                "url": "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/orgjpeg\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000058-000009AF_88_1_1000"
            }
        ],
        "smallUrl": "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/vga\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000058-000009AF_88_1_1000",
        "largeUrl": "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/scn\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000058-000009AF_88_1_1000",
        "thumbnailUrl": "http:\/\/192.168.122.1:8080\/contentstransfer\/thumb\/index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000058-000009AF_88_1_1000"
    },
    "title": "",
    "isPlayable": "false",
    "createdTime": "2018-06-18T14:20:38-04:00",
    "folderNo": "100",
    "isBrowsable": "false",
    "fileNo": "0487",
    "isProtected": "",
    "uri": "image:content?contentId=index%3A%2F%2F1000%2F00000001-default%2F00000058-000009AF_88_1_1000",
    "contentKind": "still"
}
```

To get the full-resolution image you, will need to perform a GET request on the URL at `content.original[0].url`

Comment: i was using actTakePicture, now i will try it using getContentList(), thanks for the suggestion.